# Unable to disable Cramfs & vfat using /etc/modprobe.d/ conf file

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, filesystem, modprobe

I have a security requirement that calls for me to disable several file systems that are not being used to lower attack surface.

I have created a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` and some of the file systems in that file are being disabled while others are not.

My auditing software uses `modprobe -n -v {filesystem}` to determine if a specific file system is disabled, where the file system could cramfs or vfat.

The expected output is `install /bin/true`

However, sometimes I don't get any output, which in turn causes my auditing software to say the filesystem is not disabled.

I read one post that stated the contents of that directory were rebuilt and put into a initramfs for boot time.

I tried running `update-initramfs -k all -c`, restarted, still nothing.

This is not limited to **cramfs**, it could be **vfat** or whatever. It is not a all or non issue and it is seemingly random on different systems. I also inspected my file for Windows line breaks and there are none.

I am using the AWS 16.04 build of Ubuntu but I have also tested this with a VMware instance at my office.

At the very least, I would like to figure out how I can verify these are really disabled with out having to create a new disk

Answer (score 0):

Cramfs and vfat are now built into Ubuntu and no longer loaded as modules. 
Settings in /etc/modprobe.d/* for those file systems are ignored.